# Creating a dialogue alert using a random string from a array Android

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to code a application for andriod (using eclipse) in which when a imagebutton is presses a alertdialouge comes up with a random string from and array, each time the button is pressed i would like it to change the string from the array. I have coded a alertdialouge and some code which gets a random string but it does it to a text-view instead of a alert dialouge. Can you please have a look at my code and tell me what i need to change?

```
package kevin.erica.box;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Random;

public class TheKevinAndEricaBoxActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private String[] myString;
private String list;
private static final Random rgenerator = new Random();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Resources res = getResources();

    myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.myArray); 

    list = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setText(list);
}

public void kevin(View view)
{
new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("The Box").setMessage(getResources().getText(R.string.list)).setNeutralButton("Close", null).show(); }
}
```

Comment: How do you code something you do not understand? You have an alert dialog but do not know where to change in order to have the text displayed in it?

Comment: Im learning to program by taking pieces of code other people have written and adapting it in order to learn how it works, Any idea's how to help? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you need to display a randomly selected text string from an array whenever a particular ImageButton is pressed.

Try the following code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Resources res = getResources();

   myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.myArray); 

   list = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];

   ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img_button_id);
   ib.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View arg0) {
           AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(TheKevinAndEricaBoxActivity.this);
           b.setMessage(myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)]);
           Dialog d = b.create();
           d.show();
       }
   });
}
```

Comment: im getting a error on the res. and on the new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

Comment: actually im just getting a The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined error

Comment: Please replace the line `AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);` with `AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(TheKevinAndEricaBoxActivity.this);` or whatever the name of the enclosing activity. The constructor needs a Context to be associated with. I have edited the answer too.

Answer (score 0):

```
{...

  list = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];

  TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
  tv.setText(list);
}

public void kevin(View view)
{
  new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("The Box").setMessage(getResources().getText(R.string.list)).setNeutralButton("Close", null).show(); 
}
...}
```

R.string.list is a static string that will never change during runtime, and it's defined in res/values/strings.xml

I would delete the TextView entirely and pass in the value to be displayed in the alert.

```
{...

  String randomInt = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];
  showAlert(randomInt);
}

public void showAlert(String randomInt){
  new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("The Box").setMessage(
    "Here's a random number: " + randomInt
    ).setNeutralButton("Close", null).show(); 
}

...}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change either .setTitle(), or .setMessage() to pass in your value. Something like this ought to work for you:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(list)
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // put your code here
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // put your code here 
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
```

It is easier to understand what is going on if you don't try to cram all of your chained method calls into one single line.

Also it seems like you got the variable names for these two backwards:

```
private String[] myString;
private String list;
```

Comment: Would one of you be able be able to show me a example code with this in? one of the things thats confusing me is still linking it to my button